# Preselect the product variation in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently working on a subscription based food ordering project which uses the product variations to select different options per recipe.

**Option 1(working);**
On the (man)=menu page I'm displaying each product with the corresponding variations (product -> white rice or brown rice). This works fine and customers can easily make their selection

Example:
https://puu.sh/IVDcM/c7d88428a2.png

**Option 2:**
Another option is that customer can re-order/change their menu selection (which updates the subscription with the new selection). This page is pretty much the same as **option 1**.

**Issue:**
When viewing the products on the **Option 2** page I would like to be able to show the previous selected variation options.

Comment: If its completed order in user account dashboard go to Orders -> select order and you will see order again button. Clicking it will add same product with same variations. Clicking on the product link will lead you to the product with preselected same variations.

Comment: another option is this - https://woocommerce.com/products/variation-switcher-in-cart-for-woocommerce/